# Doubt about integration over a curve

Tags: calculus, spectral-theory

I'm reading a paper and I have a doubt: Suppose we have a compact Riemannian manifold and an eigenfunction of the Laplace operator $\Delta u=-\lambda u$. Suppose in addition that we have the following gradient estimate
$$
\frac{|\nabla u|}{\sqrt{2-u^2}}\leq \sqrt{\lambda}.
$$
The paper says: Take now two points $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $u(x_1)=0$ and $u(x_2)=1$ and connect them by the shortest geodesic $\gamma(t)$ with $|\dot\gamma(t)|=1$. Then, integrating over $\gamma$, we have
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{du}{\sqrt{2-u^2}} & \leq \int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-u^2}}|\frac{du}{dt}|dt\\
& \leq \int_{\gamma}\sqrt{\lambda}dt\\
& \leq \sqrt{\lambda}d.
\end{align}
Could someone please, explain me the reason why are those the limits of integration? I think my doubt is because I'm confuse about the definition of "integration over a curve".

My attempt was the following: I think that we should take a parametrization of $\gamma:[0,l]\to M$ and then take the composition $\varphi(t):=\arcsin(\frac{u(\gamma(t))}{\sqrt 2})$. We would get

\begin{align}
|\dot \varphi(t)| & =\Big|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-u(\gamma(t))^2}}\Big\langle\nabla u_{\gamma(t)},\dot\gamma\rangle\Big|\\
& \leq \frac{|\nabla u_{\gamma(t)}|}{\sqrt{2-u(\gamma(t))^2}}
\end{align}
Then we use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and previous inequality to estimate the result
\begin{align}
|\varphi(l)-\varphi(0)| & =|\int_0^l\dot \varphi(s)ds|\\
& \leq \int_0^l |\dot \varphi(s)|ds\\
& \leq \int_0^l|\dot \varphi(s)|ds\\
& \leq \int_0^l\frac{|\nabla u|}{\sqrt{2-u^2}}dt\\
& \leq \int_0^l\sqrt \lambda dt.
\end{align}
Which would give a wrong answer. Could someone please, point out to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't have time to write out an answer, but +1 for a question displaying context, your thoughts, and your previous attempts.